# How to delete objects from the Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In the iOS Notes App you can see UITableView's cells! When you tapped the cell, and cell is passing data to the another UIViewController (for example: DetailViewController )! And inside of the DetailViewController you can delete this data from the Database!

So, I have an app with UITableView, Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController as well! I can delete data from the UITableView using default swipe to delete function! But I don't understand, how to delete them from the DetailViewController. If it's passed to the DetailViewController. If you have any suggestions please tell me. I'm very new to the iOS Development and Swift Programming Language as well.

My DetailViewController!

```
import UIKit
```

import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerLabel: UILabel!

var retrieveData:NSManagedObject!
var managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

if let demo = self.retrieveData.valueForKey("titleField") as? String {
     self.containerLabel.text = demo
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func backToMain(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Back to the MainTableViewController
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func trashButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(retrieveData)

    do {
    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {

    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably passed your managed object into the detail viewController. So let's say you have a reference to this managed object in the detail viewController called 'managedObject'. Let's also assume you have a reference to the NSManagedObjectContext called 'context'.

The code to delete this object and to save the context is:

```
context.deleteObject(managedObject)
do {
    try context.save()
    }
    catch let error{
    NSLog("Unresolved error while saving managedObjectContext: \(error)")
 }
```

After the delete, you of course need some code to update your user interface. The notes app shows the next note in the row, but you can also unwind to the UITableView in the mainscreen if you want.

The UITableView controller has to adopt the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol by implementing some delegate methods that will update the tableView. You deleted an object, so the tableView has to be notified so it can delete the row the object was in. You can find a lot of information here or elsewhere on the web how to do that. Check the protocol reference for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

Edit: if you want to pass over your context and object you will need something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier"{

        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourCustomVC{

       destinationVC.context = yourContextObject
       destinationVC.managedObject = yourManagedObject
       //pass over other data...

         }
     }
}
```

After passing over the relevant objects, your can use the given code to delete a managedObject from the context. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have fully completed a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol methods. I have passed data to another viewController using prepareForSegue method.

Comment: I have property only

Comment: I didn't understand ;(

Comment: I think you only passed over some strings instead of the managedObject itself. To be able to use the code I gave you, you'll have to pass over the context and the managedObject. In your detail view controller you also need to make some properties to hold them. See my edited answer. The new properties in this code example are called: 'managedObject' and 'context'.

Comment: Thanks dear friend! So, yes! I have used only String type properties! I'll try it today... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dear @Tuslareb ! Thanks for your help! It works very well. I have inserted some codes for dismissing a DetailViewController inside of the delete action! It also works! But I do not need like this action! I want to update my user interface like iOS Notes App! If this managedObject has been deleted! I need a 'viewDidAppear' function for doing this? Thanks again

Comment: No. When you delete a note, the iOS notes app shows the previous note in the notes list. So after a delete, you'll just have to update the user interface in the detailViewcontroller. If your note is displayed in a UITextView for example, you'll just need to update it's text property. So when you delete the object, replace the text with the text of the previous object in your fetchedResults array. To do this you will of course need all the fetched objects in your detailVC. So pass over the array or find another way to access it.

Comment: I've edited my question! I've added my detail view controller as well. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: I want to help you, but you'll have to write the code yourself. :) Please try what I said in my previous comment: 1) get all the fetched objects over; 2) delete the unwanted object; 3) figure out what the previous object is in your fetched Objects array; 4) replace the containerLabel text with the text that belongs to this previous object.

Comment: You'll learn better by trying (and failing). If you're stuck, please consider asking a new question because your current problem is about updating the user interface and not about deleting objects from core data. Also, please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: I've posted new question! Please check this out! I need your help! Thanks @Tuslareb!    http://stackoverflow.com/q/34984391/5546017