# How to update user interface on Core Data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an app with UITableView, Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController as well. I have passed data to the DetailViewController. And I can delete them from the DetailViewController! In the Apple's iOS Notes app, you can see such as functions as I wanted! When you delete a notes from the DetailViewController ( for example ), object deleted and Notes app automaticlly shows the next or previos notes! I want to create such as function. How update user interface after deleted current object? Here's my codes! Thanks `
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerLabel: UILabel!

var retrieveData:NSManagedObject!
var managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext!
var manager:Manager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.containerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.containerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.containerLabel.alpha = 0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5) { () -> Void in
        self.containerLabel.alpha = 1
    }


    if let demo = self.retrieveData.valueForKey("titleField") as? String {
     self.containerLabel.text = demo
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func backToMain(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Back to the MainTableViewController
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func trashButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(retrieveData)

    do {
    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {

    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

`

If I have 5 items on the list like so:

[image]

When I select fourth item from the list ( for example ). And detailVC shows me selected item like this:

[image]

And I want to delete them. When I delete "Four" and then my `containerLabel.text` shows previous objects from the list. They're after "Four" is deleted, "Three","Two" and "One" as well. After "One" is deleted my `containerLabel.text` shows strings

[image]

But I have left single object called as "Five"

[image]

My problem is "Five"! I can't delete it. Example: In iOS Notes App, if you have five objects on the list like my demo app. When you select fourth object from the list ( for example ). And begin deleting them, after "Four" is delete iOS Notes App shows "Five". And "Five" ( last object on the list ) is deleted and then iOS Notes App shows "Three", "Two" and "One". Maybe problem line is here:

`if index != 0 {
         self.retrieveData = fetchedObject[index! - 1]
        } else {
         self.retrieveData == fetchedObject[0]
        }`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the easy (but not so elegant) route here. You'll have to pass over all the fetched objects to the detail VC like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier"{

    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController{

        destinationVC.managedObjectContext = yourContext
        destinationVC.retrieveData = yourManagedObject
        destinationVC.arrayOfFetchedObjects = yourFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
        //pass over other data...

        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your detailVC, write a method that will be executed when you press the delete button. Something like this:

```
@IBAction func trashButton(sender: AnyObject) {

//make sure you have an array with YourObjects
guard let fetchedObjects = arrayOfFetchedObjects as? [YourObjectType] else {return}

//get index of the shown object in the array of fetched objects
let indexOfObject = fetchedObjects.indexOf(retrieveData)

//delete the object from the context
self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(retrieveData)

do {
    try self.managedObjectContext.save()

    //delete the object from the fetchedObjects array
    fetchedObjects.removeAtIndex(indexOfObject)
} catch {

}

//get the object that should be shown after the delete
if indexOfObject != 0{
    //we want the object that represents the 'older' note
    retrieveData = fetchedObjects[indexOfObject - 1]
    updateUserInterface(true)

}
else{
    //the index was 0, so the deleted object was the oldest. The object that is the oldest after the delete now takes index 0, so just use this index. Also check for an empty array.

    if fetchedObjects.isEmpty{ 
         updateUserInterface(false)
     }
    else{
        retrieveData = fetchedObjects[0]
        updateUserInterface(true)
    }

    }
}


func updateUserInterface(note: Bool){

switch note{

    case true:

        //update the user interface
        if let demo = retrieveData.valueForKey("titleField") as? String {
            self.containerLabel.text = demo
        }

    case false:

        self.containerLabel.text = "no more notes"

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I'll try it... Thanks @Tuslareb

Comment: When I have multiple items on the array, that's works well! If I have single item? Xcode gives me error like so! " fatal error: Array index out of range ".

Comment: That's because you're accessing index 0 on an empty array. So you will get an out of range error. So as I said, you'll need some code to check for an empty array before you'll try to get fetchedObjects[0]. Don't assign a new value to retrieveData in that case. You can update the user interface with a text that says: 'no notes in list' or something like that.

Comment: `if index == 0 {

            self.containerLabel.text = "No Records Are Available!"
            self.secondContainerLabel.text = ""
            self.trash.enabled = false
        } 
` It works,but doesn't shows next object on the list. Only shows previous objects. I have edited my question. Please check this out.

Comment: You are not checking for an empty array. You are just checking the index for  0. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to pass the details view controller

1. A list of all managed objects and an index for where in the list to start
2. A current managed object and a callback to get the next object

In order for it to have enough information to do what you want. The callback approach is nicest and is a simple form of delegate, where your master view controller is the delegate supplying the extra data.

Comment: I have tried many ways! But they're not works anymore! My friend @Tuslareb already been said! If I delete current object from the detailVC and it shows deleted object! Does not updated! Can you help me by code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You accepted this answer, does that mean you got it running?

Comment: I don't really understand the comment @user5546017. are you saying that the detail VC update the list and the master VC doesn't reflect that? this is a different question. ideally you should be using a fetched results controller

Comment: Dear @Wain! I'm new to the iOS Development! I have a tableView and I have fully completed NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol methods! My masterVC ( MainVC ) works perfectly! There is not any errors! I can insert, delete, update rows smoothly. I have passed data to the detailVC via prepareForSegue. And I can delete them from the detailVC. Big thanks to the @Tuslareb for that! My problem is after deleted! Because my containerLabel is still shows the deleted object! Does not updated! Are you understand? How to implement it?

Comment: Dear friend @Tuslareb! I do not test them! Because I didn't understand. How to get them? How to callback to get the next object? I need your helps! Thanks!

Comment: So have you changed your code to pass an array of objects instead of just one?

Comment: Dear @Wain! Not yet. I'll try it today!